# Full access to AWS S3 bucket for all operations except for 1 folder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have a group policy that allows full access to several S3 buckets.

This policy allows read and write to the bucket.

The team that uses these buckets wants that one of the folders will be read-only for their group without the ability to write or delete its contents.

How do I provide that while still allowing them to have full access to all the other folders?

Answer (score 3):

To allow access to "every folder except one", you will need to use an `Allow` policy and a `Deny` policy. This is because a `Deny` always overrides an `Allow`.

You should put the desired IAM Users into an IAM Group, then add a policy like this to the IAM Group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/read-only-path/*",
        }
    ]
}
```

Be a little careful with the `Allow` — it is *not* good practice to grant `s3:*` to the bucket since this is probably giving them too much permission. So, trim it down to what they actually need.